# Keep CSS Quote from Wrapping on Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a responsive blockquote that I'm styling and it looks fine until we get to the mobile version. When the screen size gets down to the bare minimum, I end up with a hanging quote that's not attaching to the end word. See image below.

I've tried adding `white-space:nowrap;` but it doesn't seem to work on just the quotation mark. Rather, it nowraps the entire quote.

**CSS:**

```
blockquote {
   background: #f9f9f9;
   border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
   margin: 1.5em 0px;
   padding: 0.5em 1em;
   quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
blockquote:before {
   color: #ccc;
   content: open-quote;
   font-size: 4em;
   line-height: 0.1em;
   margin-right: 0.25em;
   vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
blockquote:after {
   color: #ccc;
   content: close-quote;
   font-size: 4em;
   line-height: 0.1em;
   vertical-align: -0.4em;
   margin-left: 0.25em;
}
blockquote p {
   display: inline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<blockquote>
<p style="text-align: center;"><em>Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.</em></p>
</blockquote>
```

[image]

Comment: Kinda a hacky solution, but you could try to type in the quotes in the HTML and only display them on mobile, then apply a no-wrap around the end quote and last word. E.g.: `<p><span class="mobileonly">"</span>Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a <span style="white-space: nowrap">lifetime.<span class="mobileonly">"</span></span></p>`. You can then use the `.mobileonly` class to make your quotes look like they normally would.

Comment: can you share your html as well ?

Comment: Which Browser you are seeing this behaviour? I'm not seeing this in crome on windows 10: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RROpPr

Comment: Do you have whitespace at the end of the blockquote? `Lorem </blockquote>`, Then trim it.

Comment: Safari on Mac and iPhone.

Comment: Remove the newline after `</p>`. See my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the whitespace is the problem. If there is whitespace (space, tab, new line) a the end of the `blockquote` element, this behaviour will appear.

You have to trim the whitespace so there is not space right before the cloing `</blockquote>` tag.

See here for the difference: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RROpPr

---

### edit

You have to remove the newline after the end of the paragraph

```
<blockquote>
<p style="text-align: center;"><em>Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.</em></p></blockquote>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZJRZa

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of browser differences, but both appear the same. I'm using Safari on my Mac and iPhone.

Comment: Tried removing the new line, but to no effect. Wordpress doesn't recognize this change any differently, since it's a tag.

Comment: I don't know WP enough to help you with this. I think the whitespace is the problem with the false display. But how to remove the whitespace in WP is a different task and you should open a new question for that. In that new question you should paste the WP code that generates that output and ask, how you can remove the whitespace after the 'p' tag

Answer (score 0):

`blockquote { position: relative; }`

`blockquote:after { position: absolute; }`

This will fix your issue.